# How to Solve a form loading error of Client-Server

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

```
TcpListener  serverSocket = new TcpListener(ip, port);
TcpClient  clientSocket =new TcpClient();  //default tcpclient socket;

serverSocket.Start();


counter = 0;
while (true)
{
    counter += 1;
    clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

    Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "Client No:" + Convert.ToString(counter) + " started!");   
    LAN_Quiz.ClientHandle.HandleClient hc = new LAN_Quiz.ClientHandle.HandleClient();

    hc.ClientHandlingStarted(clientSocket, counter.ToString());


    //Get the client ip address

    string clientIPAddress = "Your Ip Address is: " + IPAddress.Parse(((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString()));

    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    ..
    ... 
}
```

In Windows Form Application here ,I have the problem of why form did not load when I used the

```
clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
```

and rest code

but it can accept the client request;
Now how to solve this problem and also plz give me information about the Timer uses

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to read that much code.

Comment: Simplify your sample, create readabl example.

Comment: Definitely not me.  Please simply your code and extract the place where you have a problem.  SO is not here to debug your program for you; you have to do the minimum yourself.

Comment: I think it's not too much code, in fact I love the completeness. However, TRWTF is that the question is buried somewhere inside that blob. Please describe the situation. You are using Telerik stuff (what stuff) and doing a specific type of usage (name it), perhaps point to a demo page at [telerik.com](http://www.telerik.com/support/demos/developer-tools-demos.aspx) etc

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private Thread _serverThread;

    public Form()
    {
         _serverThread = new Thread(ServerThread).Start();
    }

    private void ServerThread(object state)
    {
        //add the socket code here.
    }
}
```

That would work. However, I do not recommend it since it breaks the *Single Responsibility Principle* (google). Put all socket code in a separate class (including the thread code) and use that class from your main form.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when i used the use of Thread as mention above then form is loaded but when the client request come to the server then server form hangs up or not responding. can anyone give solve this problem providing code with in windows form I want the server to list the client name and the ipaddress and server to check whether the client is available or not and server can add any-client in it's list (listView or Data grid view)